# Headers with Double Quotation Marks

Tags: marketing-cloud, csv, header

We are trying to import a file to a data extension in SF marketing cloud via a csv file.

The data comes from another database, which add's double quotation marks around the header fields as well as the data fields.  This is problematic as SFMC sees the headers as data and hence it doesn't get imported.

Is there a way around this? We need our fields to be text qualified but i don't want to have to manually open every import and re-save as a csv.  Thanks

Comment: I would look at the possibilities of the export of your database, maybe there are some different options that you did not tested yet? the technical term of double quotation marks in this matter is text qualifier. if the columns orders are the same and you have a field type like boolean you could also try to insert without mapping but by ordinal. the header row would automaticly be skipped hence it doesnt fit to the field type like booleans, if you only have text fields this wouldnt work.